# Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore with proper imports

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this weird error in firebase when trying to query my firestore database.
I am initializing my app with the following code:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

my initializations:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup, signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail, signOut} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, query, getDocs, collection, where, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
```

I also try to run the query in these two ways and get the same error for both.

```
let userDocs = query(collection(db, 'users'))
```

and

```
let userDocs = (collection(db, 'users'))
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you share complete code so we can see how you `export` the `db` from Firebase file and `import` it where you are running the query? Just the code snippets individually look correct .

Comment: The code snippets you share look fine at first glance, so the problem is likely (as Dharmaraj also seems to suspect) in how these snippets interact. Can you show that or (even better) reproduce the problem in a single snippet?